# Expiry date of patent -US2014/0086986A1

Tags: us9247694

What is the expiry date of patent US2014/0086986A1 on Capsicum.

Comment: The cited document is only an application.

Comment: The application has been granted as US9247694B2. You need to check that document's expiration date.